# How to eval plain text php and and export the result to an html file

Tags: php, html, template-engine

I am currently trying to create a small template engine for a project that I am working on, and I am using a system where I am replacing `{$tag}` with a preset tag. So say I put `{username}` in my template file, it will return a string which is the username.  Now I want to go beyond just a simple string replacing a string.  So using the same code I put

`$tpl->replace('getID', '<?php echo "test"; ?>);`

And it didn't work, so when I went to inspect element, I saw that it returned `<!--? echo "test"; ?-->`...

So now I am just trying to figure out why it returned commented code.

Here is my class file:

```php
class template {

  private $tags = [];
  private $template;

  public function getFile($file) {
    if (file_exists($file)) {
      $file = file_get_contents($file);
      return $file;
    }
    
    return false;
  }

  public function __construct($templateFile) {
    $this->template = $this->getFile($templateFile);
    if (!$this->template) return "Error! Can't load the template file $templateFile";   
  }

  public function set($tag, $value) {
    $this->tags[$tag] = $value;
  }

  private function replaceTags() {
    foreach ($this->tags as $tag => $value) {
      $this->template = str_replace('{'.$tag.'}', $value, $this->template);
    }

    return true;
  }

  public function render() {
    $this->replaceTags();
    print($this->template);
  }

}
```

And My index file is:

```php
require_once 'system/class.template.php';

$tpl = new template('templates/default/main.php');

$tpl->set('username', 'Alexander');
$tpl->set('location', 'Toronto');
$tpl->set('day', 'Today');

$tpl->set('getID', '<?php echo "test"; ?>');

$tpl->render();
```

And my template file is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head></head>

<body>
    {getID}
  <div>
    <span>User Name: {username}</span>
    <span>Location: {location}</span>
    <span>Day: {day}</span>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

## **Clarification**

At the time when I was making the aforementioned template engine, one of my goals was to create something that would be able to take both raw php and plain text and be able to pump an output out that would just work (similar to [twig](https://twig.symfony.com)).

What I was effectively trying to ask was how do I take php code surrounded by `<?php //... ?>` and pipe the output of that as a string to be rendered in html. What I would do now is use an eval statement.  This would basically turn `$tpl->replace('getID', '<?php echo "test"; ?>);` into `$tpl->replace('getID', eval('<?php echo "test"; ?>));` which would work.  This is a much more elegant way of doing this as it allows for any static php to be piped in during execution, and the output to be piped out in plain text (or html) after resolution.

Another solution, as mentioned by [Unbranded Manchester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2722571/unbranded-manchester), is that instead of writing more php and just piping that in, I can use specialty functions that would do the job of the eval'd code. So the example would look like `$tpl->replace('getID', fetchID());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're redeclaring PHP in a php file when there is no need to. i.e. you're trying to print `<?php` which is why it's messing up.

So, you can replace this:

```
$tpl->set('getID', '<?php echo "test"; ?>');
```

with this

```
$tpl->set('getID', 'test');
```

But, you obviously already know that, you're just trying to go further, the way to do this is by using php inside the set. So, as an idea, you could try this:

```
$tpl->set('getID', testfunction());
```

(You're calling `testfunction` here to define the `'getID'` here btw)

So, now you want to write a little function to do something fancy, for the sake of this example:

```
function testfunction(){
  $a = 'hello';
  $b = 'world';
  $c = $a . ' ' . $b;
  return $c;
}
```

The above should then return hello world in place of {getID}

In reference to your comments - if you want to go one step further and start being more advanced with the return results, you can do the following:

```
function testfunction(){
  $content = "";
  foreach ($a as $b){
    ob_start();
  ?>
    <span><?php echo $b->something; ?></span>
    <a href="#">Some link</a>
    <div>Some other html</div>
    <?php 
      $content += ob_get_clean();
  }
  return $content
}
```

Comment: I should have better clarified this in the post, but the entire reason that I am trying to get the php to work is so that I am able to create things like IF, ELSE, ENDIF, FOREACH, ect.

Comment: You ought to be able to do that within functions using the above code. I.e. stick an if / else into the function above and it'll do what you need? Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: What I am trying to do is create a dynamic template engine where I can do things like {FOREACH: (x as y)} (HTML code) {END:FOREACH}.  And all of this data would be stored in a .tpl file.

Comment: Although you've completely changed the scope of the question here, answer has been updated to show you how to stick a foreach with html in.

Comment: That is also missing the entire point.  All of this goes in the template file, not the php file.I don't want it to be in the php file

Comment: Might wanna ask a new question -- *a lot more clearly*

Comment: I think I will.

Comment: @JacksonRoberts one question would be why do you need to re-invent a template engine for php when there are so many already..

Comment: @Ben I understand why you'd say that, but in this forums software that I am creating, I do not just want to use every library under the sun to get to the end, I want to make it from scratch with very few exceptions. The only exceptions I've really made are the use of SummerNote and PHPMailer.  My entire take on programming is to learn.  And for me that is learning how to do things from scratch.